# When should I use `no-eta-equality` in Agda records?

Tags: agda, eta-equality

In [a recent development](https://github.com/laMudri/generic-lr/blob/8a30233559145ea56f9f40d5615fff5bfd82f3cc/src/Generic/Linear/Example/WRel.lagda.tex#L30), I used the [`no-eta-equality`](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.2.1/language/record-types.html#eta-expansion) attribute on a record. The motivation in that case was ad hoc: I noticed that I'd get better metavariable resolution for uses of definitions like [`map-⊗ᴿ`](https://github.com/laMudri/generic-lr/blob/8a30233559145ea56f9f40d5615fff5bfd82f3cc/src/Generic/Linear/Example/WRel.lagda.tex#L90) if I could make [`_⊗ᴿ_`](https://github.com/laMudri/generic-lr/blob/8a30233559145ea56f9f40d5615fff5bfd82f3cc/src/Generic/Linear/Example/WRel.lagda.tex#L70) more opaque. However, it got me wondering whether I could be taking more advantage of `no-eta-equality` by recognising some patterns in which it is useful.

Are there any best practices or heuristics to decide whether to use `no-eta-equality` on a given record? Are there cases where both choices are justifiable? And what are the costs and benefits in each case?

Comment: Perhaps *eta-equality* would be the better name for the tag, though it's not so different in meaning from *eta-conversion* (I don't think I'd usually say “eta-conversion” myself – I'd prefer “eta-equality”, “eta-expansion”, or “eta-contraction”, depending on what I wanted to talk about). I don't think this is necessarily an Agda-specific question; the mapping to language-agnostic theoretical concepts is straightforward. I doubt there would be many more questions you could ask with the *agda-no-eta-equality* tag.

Answer (score 3):

When you're absolutely sure you don't need it. Then disabling eta equality for a record saves time for Agda. For instance, the [Iso](https://github.com/agda/cubical/blob/66e2d01eec51744ddcb9e6c80bef52617369e1a7/Cubical/Foundations/Isomorphism.agda#L35-L42) type for isomorphism is mostly used to carry the information of an isomorphism, and then convert it to a HoTT-sense of equivalence and then send it to the `Glue` type former. So, it adds `no-eta-equality` to improve performance of type checking.

Apart from performance, coinductive records also require the absence of eta equality to work. So if you want to do some beautiful guarded corecursion then you need `no-eta-equality`. But this is implied by the `coinductive` keyword which you put at the same place where you put `no-eta-equality`, so you don't actually need to write it out when using `coinductive`.

Comment: I think this leaves out the key part: if I were writing library code, *how* could I know that no user would need η-equality? IIUC, the example you give works because `Iso` is essentially a helper structure that we don't pass around terms of. But even this surprises me: it makes smart constructors like `isoToEquiv` and `isoToPath` have different elaboration behaviour to uncurried versions of them.